# Input text only visible on mouse leave and reenter in IE8 using Bootstrap popover

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, internet-explorer-8

I have a website with a login form that opens when I click a login-link. This form is nested in a Bootstrap-Popover. 
Everything works just fine, except in IE8: The form is displayed when i click the link, but when I enter a text in the input fields its invisible until I leave and then reenter the popover with the mouse. It seems the popover is not properly focused.

Is there a way to simulate the mouse leave and enter with javascript (jQuery) when the mouse is still on the container?

Unfortunately I can't post any html/css/js because the files are very large...

Comment: My guess is that there is faulty CSS or HTML markup that's causing the symptoms. It might be beneficial if you can create a minimal example that exhibits the problems and then include that here.

Comment: I will try to create an example, but its a very large application I didn't develop myself. I'm only responsible for bugfixing. The developers also have no idea what causes the problem...

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle for this?